# Geometry : $(AD+DE)^2+BD^2=(AB+BE)^2$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a right triangle where $\angle C=90^{\circ}$ and $\angle A=10^{\circ}$.

Point D and E are on the sides AC and BC respectively such that $\angle ABD = \angle CDE = 60^{\circ}$.

Prove that $(AD+DE)^2+BD^2=(AB+BE)^2$

[image]

My attempt :

Draw line $BD$ and extend $BD$ through $D$ to meet the perpendicular from $A$ at $F$, $AF\perp BD$

Let $ED$ cut $AF$ at point $T$.

$\angle CBF = \angle CAF = 20^{\circ} \rightarrow B, C, F, A$ concyclic.

so $\angle BCA = \angle BFC = \angle BDE = 10^{\circ}$

so $DE \parallel CF$ and $ET \parallel CF$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M\in AB$ such that $B$ placed between $M$ and $A$ and $MB=BE$ and

$K\in AC$ such that $C$ be a midpoint of $KD$.

Hence, since $\measuredangle CDE=60^{\circ}$, we have $AK=AD+DK=AD+DE$.

Also, $AM=AB+BM=AB+BE$.

Thus, it remains to prove that $MK=BD$ and $\measuredangle MKA=90^{\circ}$.

From here I used trigonometry:

We can show that a projection of $MB$ on the line $AC$ is equale to $KC$,

which gives that $\measuredangle MKA=90^{\circ}$.

Now, we can show that $MK=BD$ and it ends the proof by the Pythagoras theorem.

Maybe it will help and you'll  find something nicer.

I'll prove that $MK=BD$ if you proved that $MK\perp AK$.

Let $AB=a$.

Hence, by law of sines for $\Delta ABD$ we obtain:
$$\frac{BD}{\sin10^{\circ}}=\frac{a}{\sin70^{\circ}}$$ or
$$BD=\frac{a\sin10^{\circ}}{\sin70^{\circ}}.$$
Now, by law of sines for $\Delta BED$ we obtain:
$$\frac{BE}{\sin10^{\circ}}=\frac{\frac{a\sin10^{\circ}}{\sin70^{\circ}}}{\sin150^{\circ}},$$
which gives
$$MB=BE=\frac{2a\sin^210^{\circ}}{\sin70^{\circ}}.$$
Thus, 
$$AM=AB+BM=a+\frac{2a\sin^210^{\circ}}{\sin70^{\circ}}=\frac{a(\sin70^{\circ}+1-\cos20^{\circ})}{\sin70^{\circ}}=\frac{a}{\sin70^{\circ}},$$
which says
$$MK=AM\sin10^{\circ}=\frac{a\sin10^{\circ}}{\sin70^{\circ}}=BD.$$

Comment: I get stuck on one point, to prove that $MK=BD$. I got $BK=BD, \angle BME =  \angle BEM = 40^{\circ}, \angle EKD =  \angle EDK = 60^{\circ}, \angle KEC = 30^{\circ}, MEK = 110^{\circ}$. I've tried to apply Trigonometry but didn't get the result.

Comment: @carat I added something. See now please.

Comment: I'm clear now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @carat You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Take $F$ reflection of $D$ about $C$, $\triangle DEF$ is equilateral, take then $G$ on $AB$ so that $FG\bot AC$ to get $FG=FB=BD$ ($\widehat{FGB}=\widehat{FBG}=80^\circ$). Also $\widehat{BFE}=\widehat{BDE}=10^\circ$. Now take $H$, reflection of $E$ about $BF$, see that $\triangle BGH$ is equilateral, so $BG=BH=BE$, done, since $AG^2=AF^2+FG^2$.[image]